# Element unable to catch by selenium python by xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I try get the element `div[@class='search hide-input a-right']` on site. In selectorhub I validate and sh sees that's element. But selenium doesn't locate this.

And I see this error in sh
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/znCWG.png

Comment: Please post the Relevant html or Url of the page?

Comment: @KunduK seart.pl you have to change width to 725px

Answer (score 0):

The element is in fact present, however, Selenium does not allow to interact with invisible elements because a user could not do so either. There are some workarounds though (e.g. via jsExecutor). The error in your screnshot pretty much tells you about this circumstance.
The takeaway here is: An element being present in DOM does not equal to being visible/interactible.

Comment: But it's just search icon.  It's is visible and interactible. https://prnt.sc/4ge_4mBeQ9At

Comment: How to handle with that?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you're targeting the correct element. As suggested in the error message, trying a nearby element in the DOM is a good place to check first.

If another element sits on top of another (its z-index is higher, for example), you can't interact with an element underneath it. There are many reasons why a particular element in the DOM may not be interactable. The trick is to make sure you're finding the element that actually captures the click event (or the element that passes the pointer events).

An example of this is that `<input>` checkbox/radio elements are sometimes hidden or positioned off-screen using CSS because their corresponding `<label>` is actually the element that controls the checkbox/radio state and can be seen in the UI. The `<input>` element may not be intractable, but the `<label>` element is.

As a *possible* workaround, you can also try triggering a click event using javascript via `.execute_script`. This works because javascript is allowed to interact with elements in ways the user (or webdriver interface) cannot.

```py
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ...)
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', element)
```

Though keep in mind, if you're targeting the wrong element, you may still fail to cause the intended action. For example, if the intended action is triggered by an `onClick` listener on a particular element, but you're not clicking the correct element with the listener, this workaround obviously doesn't solve that problem.